# Does it matter if nginx frontend (rev proxy) uses different SSL certificate than backend server?

Tags: ssl, nginx

I have a backend server written in Node.js which currently works as a SSL server. I have nginx set up to reverse-proxy to this backend, and it also has SSL support. I plan to have multiple frontends that access the same backend, though, and the frontends themselves might use different SSL certificates. Does it matter if nginx users different SSL cert compared to backend? Does backend need to use SSL at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i would say that you don't need ssl on the backend servers.

i mean: how big is the probability that someone intercepts the connection between the reverse proxy and the backends? In most cases they are at the same location.

Comment: In my case, they _are_ at the same location, so I guess I don't need it. :) Thanks.